# Post Request express: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I'm fairly new to Node.js and I am having some issues.
im working on app for learning purposes but i came across this problem 
Error: Can't render headers after they are sent to the client.
i didnt know how to make it work

> C:\Users\GameDev\Desktop\Portfolio\reciepe\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:437
>         throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
>         ^
>   Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
>       at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
>       at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\GameDev\Desktop\Portfolio\reciepe\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
>       at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\GameDev\Desktop\Portfolio\reciepe\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
>       at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\GameDev\Desktop\Portfolio\reciepe\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
>       at C:\Users\GameDev\Desktop\Portfolio\reciepe\routes\route.js:32:20
>       at Query. (C:\Users\GameDev\Desktop\Portfolio\reciepe\models\orm.js:9:9)
>       at Query. (C:\Users\GameDev\Desktop\Portfolio\reciepe\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:525:10)
>       at Query._callback (C:\Users\GameDev\Desktop\Portfolio\reciepe\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:491:16)
>       at Query.Sequence.end (C:\Users\GameDev\Desktop\Portfolio\reciepe\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)
>       at Query.ErrorPacket (C:\Users\GameDev\Desktop\Portfolio\reciepe\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:90:8)

SQL error : 
code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage:
   'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near \'NULL, 
\'dqdd\'\' at line 1',
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql:
   'INSERT INTO authentication(username,password)  VALUES NULL, \'dqdd\'' }

here is the database

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database:'reciepeapp'
});

module.exports  = con
```

the ORM

```
  const con = require('./db')

    const orm = {

      insertOne: function (values, cb) {

 const sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO authentication(username,password)  VALUES ?";
    con.query(sqlQuery, [values],function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        cb(err, null);
      } else {
        cb(null, data);
      }
  });
    },


    }
    module.exports = orm;
```

here is the route.js

```
  const express = require('express');
    const app = express()
    const router = express.Router()
    const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

    const orm = require('../models/orm')
    router.get('/',(req,res)=>
        res.render('home')
    )
    router.get('/login',(req,res)=>
        res.render('login')
    )
    router.get('/register',(req,res)=>
        res.render('register')
    )
    router.post("/register", function (req, res) {
        values = [
            username = req.body.username,
            password = req.body.password
        ];


        orm.insertOne(values, function(error) {

            if (error) {
                return res.status(401).json({
                    message: 'Not able to add'
                });
            }
            return res.json({
                username: values.username,
                password:values.password

            });
        });
    });
    module.exports = router
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const indexRouter = require('./routes/route')
const con = require('./models/db')
con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error('error: ' + err.message);
    }

    console.log('Connected to the MySQL server.');
  });
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
console.log(__dirname)
app.use('/',express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.use('/',indexRouter)
const PORT = 5000;
app.listen(PORT,()=>console.log('it started on 5000'))
```

May I know what is wrong with my code?

Comment: can you show the stack error ??

Comment: Try putting the else statement inside the callback instead of directly returning. if(error) { return res; } else {return res}

Comment: Please don't edit the fix into your question.  As your question stands now, it makes no sense and is useless as a reference to others because you edited the solution into the question.

Comment: yes u are right , i will make sure won't do that next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `orm` file. There the callback is getting called twice(in case `err` is true/has a value), which in-turn calls the `res.json` twice. Try changing the below

```
con.query(sqlQuery, [values],function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      cb(err, null);
    } else {
      cb(null, data);
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer , i replace and indeed the error is gone but when i add data to the register form it gave me the error      message: 'Not able to add'

Comment: try to console log your `err` in `orm` to display the error.

Comment: there are many issues.. your values under `route.js` should be an `object` instead of `array` like `values = { username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password }` and then use  `con.query('insert into authentication set ?', values, function (err, data) {` which would be similar to what they have mentioned in the `mysql` npm readme.